Custom Widget for saving data QT Designer
I am developing a small application, as a start I am creating a dialog using QT Designer. Is there a custom widget for creating a file output as per the image below?

I looked here but could not find any or perhaps missed it out:


QgsFileWidget is probably what you are looking for (it's in the list of custom widgets). *BTW, the first image you've shown above is a QgsProcessingLayerOutputDestinationWidget(https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/gui/processing/qgsprocessingoutputdestinationwidget.cpp) which is slightly different since it's designed to work with processing parameters as part of the processing architecture.

Thanks Ben. I will look into it and give you a feedback once done.
